# Swagger 2.9.2 to Swagger 3.0.0

Tags: swagger

I use sprinfox.swagger 2.9.2

How can I change my configuration from:

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
          .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
     
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
          .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
```

to configuration 3.0.0?

because this doesn't work:

```
   @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui/index.html")
              .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
         
            registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
              .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
        }
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What happens when that code is run in 3.0.0? Why is that wrong?

Comment: when i try run localhost:8081/myproject/swagger_ui/index.html
I don't see appropriate page.

Comment: hen i try run localhost:8081/myproject/swagger-ui/index.html I don't see appropriate page